# Valuation on integral domain

Tags: commutative-algebra, valuation-theory

In order to prepare for a seminar I am currently studying valuation rings and I have stumbled upon the following statement:

> Let $A\neq 0$ be a commutative, unitary ring and $\mathfrak{p}$ a prime ideal and $\vert\cdot\vert$ some valuation on $A/\mathfrak{p}$ (here is the error: it must be $\operatorname{Frac}(A/\mathfrak{p})$) Then the support $\{ x\in A/\mathfrak{p} : \vert x \vert =0\} =(0)$.

I have tried that the ring I'm investigating is integral, thus $ab\neq 0$ whenever $a,b\neq 0$, but this has not gotten me anywhere.

P.S. in this notation a valuation on $A$ is a multiplicative map $\vert\cdot\vert:A\to \Gamma\cup \{0\}$ where $\Gamma$ is a totally ordered, abelian group s.t. 0,1 map to 0,1 resp. and s.t. $\vert a+b\vert \le \max(\vert a\vert, \vert b\vert),\ \forall a,b\in A$.

Comment: Why need a prime ideal? Just assume that A is an integral domain.

Comment: If $\Gamma$ is a group don't you have $0\in\Gamma$?

Comment: I think, nilsw is using multiplicative notation, that's why he adds $0$ to $\Gamma$.

Comment: Could you post your source? This isn’t true as you’ve stated it.

Comment: @AlexMathers: my source is adic spaces by Wedhorn. In particular what is leading up to 1.2.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The important point is that it's not assumed just that $|\cdot|$ is a valuation on $A/\mathfrak p$ but rather it's a valuation on $k(\mathfrak p)=\operatorname{Frac}(A/\mathfrak p)$. Valuations on fields automatically have $\operatorname{supp}(|\cdot|)=\{0\}$ (because the support is a prime ideal).

To see why the claim as originally stated can't be true, it's important to note that if $A$ is an integral domain you could take $\mathfrak p=(0)$ and then the claim would be that every valuation on an integral domain has zero support, for which you have simple counterexamples on, say, $A=\mathbb Z$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I somehow thought that $\kappa(\mathfrak{p})$ was just $A/\mathfrak{p}$. Thanks for the clarification and know I think I understand completely!

Answer (score 0):

I think I might have come up with an answer. One can extend the valuation to a valuation on $K=Frac(A/\mathfrak{p})$ this extended valuation has trivial kernel, which then proves the claim.

Edit: see Alex Mathers's answer for a correct and complete answer. There has been an error in the original phrasing of the question.